# Which css property should i use to disable text selection only on select all command?

Tags: html, css

what css class should i use to disable text selection only when i pressed Ctrl+A and not while am selecting it manually? i have tried this but this class not allowed me to select the text manually.

```
.title h3 {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: You want to disable CTRL+A?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a CSS attribute for that. However, you could easily add this feature by adding the following javascript snippet to your html file:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      var triggerKey = e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey;
      if (e.keyCode === 65 && triggerKey) {
          return e.preventDefault(); }
      }
  );
</script>
```

If you don't need to worry about OSX (Mac), just remove the `e.metaKey` declaration since that targets the command (⌘) key.